# Accuracy assessment in Erdas imagine

Tags: remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, accuracy

Is it necessary to do an accuracy assessment for an unsupervised classification done for a Landsat 5 image?

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. Your question is too broad to be answered properly. In short, yes, a validation (=accuracy assessment) of classification results is always recommended!

Answer (score 1):

When an accuracy assessment is being performed an error matrix would be generated and kappa. From there you would notice that omission and commision error is there from which the producer and user accuracy can be calculated from the formula given below:

**Producer Accuracy = 100 - omission error**  and 
**User Accuracy = 100 - commission error**

From the calculated values above if the user accuracy is between 70-100% then you are good to go otherwise you have to reclassify for good results.